# Problema al ejecutar app Android en Xamarin Studio

Tags: android, c#, xamarin

Cada vez que intento ejecutar una app Android en Xamarin Studio (Mac), ésta se detiene, luego de que se cargue el emulador. No modifiqué absolutamente nada del código fuente que viene por default, y uso el emulador predeterminado de Xamarin.

Me aparece esta advertencia mientras se ejecuta el emulador:

> Warning: No -tsa or -tsacert is provided and this jar is not
>   timestamped. Without a timestamp, users may not be able to validate
>   this jar after the signer certificate's expiration date (2046-11-18)
>   or after any future revocation date.

¿Alguien sabe cuál puede ser el motivo?

Comment: tu error se debe a el tiempo de ejecucion, debes cambiar la zona horaria de tu windows 10, a zona horaria de canada, con eso se resuelve

Comment: ya actualizaste tus paquetes nuggets?

Comment: No, y la verdad es que no sé cuál es el significado y la función de los nuggets. ¿Me podrás explicar?

Comment: creo saber e, detalle de tu problema, de casualidad no tendras instalado el JDK y el JRE en tu mac?, hay veces que suele pasar esto debido a lo que te comente

Answer (score 0):

El mensaje indica el warning y la solución.:

> Warning: No -tsa or -tsacert is provided and this jar is not
>   timestamped. Without a timestamp, users may not be able to validate
>   this jar after the signer certificate's expiration date (2046-11-18)
>   or after any future revocation date.

Tu aplicación requiere un [certificado](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/code_signing_understanding_who_and) el cual no es aceptado por la fecha, **tienes que configurar tu sistema con la fecha y hora correcta.**

---

El error mostrado es :

> Unable to get provider mono.MonoRuntimeProvider: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to find application Mono.Android.Platform.ApiLevel_24 or Xamarin.Android.Platform

Tienes que instalar Android 7.0 (API 24)

Comment: Es que la configuración de la zona horaria, aparentemente, coincide con la de mi equipo. Te dejo una captura de pantalla: https://www.dropbox.com/s/54aq9pkezpgh55z/Captura%20de%20pantalla%202016-12-30%20a%20las%2018.19.33.png?dl=0

Comment: Cambia a la opción "Use network provider time", trata y dime que obtienes.

Comment: Probé y el error sigue. Ahora que me doy cuenta, esto es un **warning**, no un error, así que probablemente el hecho de que la app se detenga siempre no tenga relación con éste...

Comment: ok! definitivamente debe ser otra cosa la que causa el cierre, que mensaje se muestra en la consola??

Comment: Esto es lo último que me aparece en la salida de la aplicación: https://www.dropbox.com/s/e92lhq3d4bml2vr/Captura%20de%20pantalla%202016-12-30%20a%20las%2019.07.56.png?dl=0